# SQL Server : SUM revenue for every single tickets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.tickets
```

My table has a bit more columns, but let's say it looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+
| Ticket  | Revenue|
+---------+--------+
| 5231    |   233  |
| 141     |   180  |
| 141     |   135  |
| 5231    |   111  |
| 5231    |   98   |
| 3228    |   539  |
+---------+--------+
```

And I want the result like this:

```
+---------+--------+
| Ticket  | Revenue|
+---------+--------+
| 5231    |   442  |
| 141     |   315  |
| 3228    |   539  |
+---------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this result?

I got a little bit complicated situation because I'm using UNION ALL in my query and when I'm trying to use SUM on Revenue and GROUP BY on Ticket I'm getting this error:

> Column 'union_all.Company' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

And I'm getting this error until I write all columns in `GROUP BY`, but even when I do this it doesn't work.

Here's all my query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ([ProductRevenue] + [ServiceRevenue]) AS [Total Revenue]
FROM
    (SELECT
         pr.company_name AS [CompanyName],
         pr.sr_service_recid AS [Ticket],
         pr.Line_Desc AS [Description],
         pr.invoice_number AS [Invoice Number],
         ih.Invoice_Type AS [InvoiceType],
         pr.date_invoice AS [DateInvoice],
         CASE
            WHEN vs.Ticket_Owner_First_Name IS NULL
                 AND vs.Ticket_Owner_Last_Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Product'
            ELSE (vs.Ticket_Owner_First_Name + ' ' + vs.Ticket_Owner_Last_Name) 
         END [Tech],
         pr.Date_Entered AS [DateEntered],
         ih.Date_Closed AS [DateClosed],
         ih.Date_Invoice AS [WorkDate],
         ih.AGR_Hours AS [HrsActual],
         ih.AGR_Hours AS [Bill],
         ih.AGR_Hours AS [NC],
         ih.AGR_Hours AS [NB],
         ih.Adj_Amount AS [Rate],
         pr.unit_price AS [InvoiceAmount],
         DATEDIFF(day, pr.Date_Entered, getdate()) AS [Age],
         CASE
            WHEN pr.unit_price >= 0
               THEN pr.unit_price
               ELSE 0
         END [ProductRevenue],
         [ServiceRevenue] = 0 
     FROM
         Product pr
     LEFT JOIN 
         InvoiceHeader ih ON ih.Billing_Log_RecID = pr.Billing_Log_RecID 
                          AND ih.Company_RecID = pr.company_recid
     LEFT JOIN 
        SRService sr ON pr.sr_service_recid = sr.SR_Service_RecID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Service vs ON vs.SR_Service_RecID = pr.sr_service_recid
    --PRODUCT SELECT--
    UNION ALL
    --SERVICES SELECT--
    SELECT
        vt.company_name AS [CompanyName],
        vt.SR_Service_RecID AS [Ticket],
        vt.charge_to AS [Description],
        vt.invoice_number AS [InvoiceNumber],
        ih.Invoice_Type AS [InvoiceType],
        vt.date_invoice AS[DateInvoice],
        ISNULL(tecf.User_Defined_Field_Value, vt.first_name + ' ' + vt.last_name) AS [Tech],
        sr.Date_Entered AS [DateEntered],
        sr.Date_Closed AS [DateClosed],
        vt.Date_Start AS [WorkDate],
        vt.hours_actual AS [HrsActual],
        CASE 
            WHEN vt.option_id = 'B'   
               THEN vt.hours_actual 
               ELSE 0 
        END [Bill],
        CASE 
            WHEN vt.option_id = 'NC'  
               THEN vt.hours_actual 
               ELSE 0 
        END [NC],
        CASE 
            WHEN vt.option_id = 'NB'  
               THEN vt.hours_actual 
               ELSE 0 
        END [NB],
        CASE 
            WHEN vt.Hourly_Rate < 25  
               THEN 0.00 
               ELSE vt.Hourly_Rate 
        END [Rate],
        vt.Billable_Hrs * CASE   
            WHEN 
                vt.Hourly_Rate < 25 
            THEN 
                0.00 
            ELSE 
                vt.Hourly_Rate 
        END [InvoiceAmount],
        DATEDIFF(day, sr.Date_Entered, getdate()) AS [Age],
        [ProductRevenue] = 0,
        CASE
            WHEN pr.item_desc = 'Product Development' 
               THEN 0
               ELSE vt.Billable_Hrs * vt.Hourly_Rate
        END [ServiceRevenue]
    FROM 
        Time vt
    LEFT JOIN 
        SRService sr ON sr.SR_Service_RecID = vt.SR_Service_RecID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Service vs ON vs.SR_Service_RecID = vt.SR_Service_RecID
    LEFT JOIN 
        TimeEntryCustomFields tecf ON (vt.Time_RecID = tecf.Time_RecID) 
                                   AND (vt.Time_Sheet_RecID = tecf.Time_Sheet_RecID) 
                                   AND (tecf.User_Defined_Field_RecID = 35)
    LEFT JOIN 
        Product pr ON pr.sr_service_recid = vt.SR_Service_RecID
    LEFT JOIN 
        InvoiceHeader ih ON vt.Invoice_Number = ih.Invoice_Number
    )   
    UNION ALL
    WHERE 
        [Invoice Number] IS NULL 
        AND [DateInvoice] IS NULL 
        AND [CompanyName] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If using `GROUP BY` is giving errors, show the code And the error. But, first, read online tutorials about how to use it?